# Is that possible to restore a text given unified diff and the original text with python

Tags: python, diff, restore

What I want is to calculate the diff delta of two texts(original and new), store the original text the delta, then expect to restore the new text. So that I can store different versions of one text with minimum space.

With Python's difflib, this could be done with ndiff and restore; however the delta of ndiff contains everything of the new text, which is at odds with my intention.

unified_diff offers a more compact delta by showing only the difference, which is desirable, but I can't find a way to restore the new text with its delta and the original one.

I've read some discussions like [this one](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/40032-restore-unified-diff), which said the delta from unified_diff alone can possibly be used to restore either text, but what I'm not sure is why not with the original text.

Answer (score 3):

I've found [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) which does exactly what I want.